# Laravel Eloquent ORM hasMany where other pivoted relationship exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I would like to query all models of a hasMany relationship that also have a pivoted relationship with a specified other model.

Example:

```
Customer:
  belongsToMany -> Entry
EntryGroup:
  hasMany -> Entry
Entry:
  belongsToMany -> Customer
  belongsTo -> EntryGroup
```

The belongsToMany relationship between Customer and Entry is stored in a pivot table.

I now want to collect the relationship to all Entries that belong to a specified Customer on an EntryGroup. Without this filtering restriction, I would have a function like

```
class EntryGroup extends Model
{
    ...

    public function entries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Entry::class);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 0):

try this one 
$customers->entries()->with('entryGroup')->get();

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?PHP

   $customerId = 5;

    Entry::whereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($customerId) {
        $query->where('id', $customerId);
    })->has("EntryGroup")->get();
```

This return all the entry has a entrygroup and belong to customer id 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$entryGroup->entries()->whereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($customerId) {
    $query->where('customers.id', $customerId);
})->get();
```